# Serializing sorted maps in Clojure / EDN?

Tags: clojure, sortedmap, edn

How can I serialize and deserialize a sorted map in Clojure?

For example:

```
(sorted-map :a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5)
{:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :d 4, :e 5}
```

What I've noticed:

1. A sorted map is displayed in the same way as an unsorted map in the REPL. This seems convenient at times but inconvenient at others.
2. [EDN](https://github.com/edn-format/edn) does not have support for [sorted maps](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/sorted-map).
3. Clojure does support [custom tagged literals for the reader](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Tagged%20Literals).

Additional resources:

- [Correct usage of data-readers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/B4_uGy1VhnA)
- [Clojure reader literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022686/what-advantage-are-clojures-1-4-reader-literals-and-why-wont-sample-compile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same question with two usable answers: [Saving+reading sorted maps to a file in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347836/savingreading-sorted-maps-to-a-file-in-clojure).

A third answer would be to set up custom reader literals. You'd print sorted maps as something like

```
;; non-namespaced tags are meant to be reserved
#my.ns/sorted-map {:foo 1 :bar 2}
```

and then use an appropriate data function when reading (converting from a hash map to a sorted map). There's a choice to be made as to whether you wish to deal with custom comparators (which is a problem impossible to solve in general, but one can of course choose to deal with special cases).

`clojure.edn/read` accepts an optional `opts` map which may contain a `:reader` key; the value at that key is then taken to be a map specifying which data readers to use for which tags. See `(doc clojure.edn/read)` for details.

As for printing, you could install a custom method for `print-method` or use a custom function for printing your sorted maps. I'd probably go with the latter solution -- implementing built-in protocols / multimethods for built-in types is not a great idea in general, so even when it seems reasonable in a particular case it requires extra care etc.; simpler to use one's own function.

*Update:*

Demonstrating how to reuse `IPersistentMap`'s `print-method` impl cleanly, as promised in a comment on David's answer:

```
(def ^:private ipm-print-method
  (get (methods print-method) clojure.lang.IPersistentMap))

(defmethod print-method clojure.lang.PersistentTreeMap
  [o ^java.io.Writer w]
  (.write w "#sorted/map ")
  (ipm-print-method o w))
```

With this in place:

```
user=> (sorted-map :foo 1 :bar 2)
#sorted/map {:bar 2, :foo 1}
```

Comment: NB. the `clojure.edn` namespace has been introduced in Clojure 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

In `data_readers.clj`:

```
{sorted/map my-app.core/create-sorted-map}
```

Note: I wished that this would work, but it did not (not sure why):

```
{sorted/map clojure.lang.PersistentTreeMap/create}
```

Now, in `my-app.core`:

```
(defn create-sorted-map
  [x]
  (clojure.lang.PersistentTreeMap/create x))

(defmethod print-method clojure.lang.PersistentTreeMap
  [o ^java.io.Writer w]
  (.write w "#sorted/map ")
  (print-method (into {} o) w))
```

As an alternative -- less low-level, you can use:

```
(defn create-sorted-map [x] (into (sorted-map) x))
```

The tests:

```
(deftest reader-literal-test
  (testing "#sorted/map"
    (is (= (sorted-map :v 4 :w 5 :x 6 :y 7 :z 8)
           #sorted/map {:v 4 :w 5 :x 6 :y 7 :z 8}))))

(deftest str-test
  (testing "str"
    (is (= "#sorted/map {:v 4, :w 5, :x 6, :y 7, :z 8}"
           (str (sorted-map :v 4 :w 5 :x 6 :y 7 :z 8))))))
```

Much of this was adapted from the resources I found above.

Note: I am surprised that `print-method` works, above. It would seem to me that `(into {} o)` would lose the ordering and thus bungle up the printing, but it works in my testing. I don't know why.

Comment: The tests pass because they are small, so basically "by accident" (of implementation details of Clojure). (The size of the tests matters because for small maps `(into {} ...)` creates array maps, which preserve insertion order. These are then converted to hash maps when they grow sufficiently large.) `clojure.lang.PersistentTreeMap/create` is a symbol naming a Java method; these are not first-class in Clojure. You could wrap it in a function -- `#(clojure.lang.PersistentTreeMap/create %)` -- which would than be usable as a value, but actually your current solution looks better to me.

Comment: If you want to reuse the existing implementation of `print-method` for `clojure.lang.IPersistentMap` with tweaks, you can (1) extract it with `(get (methods print-method) clojure.lang.IPersistentMap)` (it's just a function), (2) store it somewhere convenient, (3) call it from your own implementation of `print-method`. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate.